# Javascript - clearInterval() is not working

Tags: javascript

I need help on fixing error for `clearInterval()`. I defined `clearInterval()` inside of `setInterval()`.

Can I define `clearInterval()` inside of `setInterval()`?

```js
function neha() {

    var timeleft = 5000;
    setInterval(
        function() {
            // Success
            document.getElementById("nehaSuccess").innerHTML = "I'm done, today I will eat sandwich";

            // Show countdown
            timeleft--;
            document.getElementById("countdowntimer").textContent = timeleft;
            if (timeleft <= 0) {
                clearInterval(); // how I do clearInterval
            }
        },
        5000
    );
    // Pending
    document.getElementById("nehaPending").innerHTML = "I'm working right now, I need 5 seconds";

}

neha();
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>Neha</li>
    <li>;( -
        <span id="nehaPending"></span>
        <span id="nehaCountdowntimer"> Time remaning:  </span>
    </li>
    <li>;) - <span id="nehaSuccess"></span> </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: setInterval() returns a token that must be passed to clearInterval as an argument

Comment: `setInterval` returns an ID, put it in a variable and pass that to `clearInterval`

Comment: There is one more error in your code, check the answer I have posted

Comment: `clearInterval` needs timer ID as parameter, but you can't pass timer ID to the function, because it is null yet. If you are gonna use the ID inside an asynchronous function such as event handler, it must work. However, this case doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

You need to store setInterval token and then clear with it

```
var intervalId = setInterval(()=>{}, 50);
clearInterval(); // does nothing;
clearInterval(intervalId );// works fine
```

```js
function neha() {
    var interval;
    var timeleft = 5000;
    interval =  setInterval(
        function() {
            // Success
            document.getElementById("nehaSuccess").innerHTML = "I'm done, today I will eat sandwich";

            // Show countdown
            timeleft--;
            document.getElementById("countdowntimer").textContent = timeleft;
            if (timeleft <= 0) {
                clearInterval(interval); // how I do clearInterval
            }
        },
        5000
    );
    // Pending
    document.getElementById("nehaPending").innerHTML = "I'm working right now, I need 5 seconds";

}

neha();
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>Neha</li>
    <li>;( -
        <span id="nehaPending"></span>
        <span id="nehaCountdowntimer"> Time remaning:  </span>
    </li>
    <li>;) - <span id="nehaSuccess"></span> </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: In your answer, please explain what you did, and why.

Answer (score 3):

You have to tell `clearInterval` which interval you want to clear! (It will be the return value of the `setInterval` function).

```
var myInterval = setInterval(function () {
    do_stuff();
    if (someCondition()) {
        clearInterval(myInterval);
    }
}, 5000);
```

Comment: There is one more error in OP's code.

Comment: Do you really think `myInterval` can be used inside the function `setInterval`, though it is not executed yet?

Comment: @Miron — "though it is not executed yet" … err … it **is** executed by that time.

Comment: @Quentin, I am sure that you think wrong. If `clearInterval` is inside any asynchronous function like event handler and the variable `myInterval` is a global variable, it should work. But your example can't work.

Comment: @Miron — `clearInterval` is inside an asynchronous function! The function is asynchronous **because it is called by `setInterval`**! http://jsbin.com/susuzadiki/1/edit?js,console (`myInterval` doesn't need to be global, just in scope).

Comment: @Quentin, I was wrong. Your answer works well, I tested it. +1 ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the `timer` to the `clearInterval`,

```
var timer = setInterval(
```

and

```
clearInterval(timer);
```

**also you need to use the correct id `nehaCountdowntimer`** instead of `countdowntimer`

```
document.getElementById("nehaCountdowntimer").textContent = timeleft;
```

**Demo**

```js
function neha() {

    var timeleft = 5000;
    var timer = setInterval(
        function() {
            // Success
            document.getElementById("nehaSuccess").innerHTML = "I'm done, today I will eat sandwich";

            // Show countdown
            timeleft--;
            document.getElementById("nehaCountdowntimer").textContent = timeleft; //observe this line
            if (timeleft <= 0) {
                clearInterval(timer); // how I do clearInterval
            }
        },
        5000
    );
    // Pending
    document.getElementById("nehaPending").innerHTML = "I'm working right now, I need 5 seconds";

}

neha();
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>Neha</li>
    <li>;( -
        <span id="nehaPending"></span>
        <span id="nehaCountdowntimer"> Time remaning:  </span>
    </li>
    <li>;) - <span id="nehaSuccess"></span> </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: He's asking if `clearInterval` can be used inside `setInterval`.

Comment: Off course, I have added a demo of the same as well.

Answer (score -1):

Following code should be work

```
 function neha() {

        var timeleft = 5000;
        var interval = setInterval(
            function() {
                // Success
                document.getElementById("nehaSuccess").innerHTML = "I'm done, today I will eat sandwich";

                // Show countdown
                timeleft--;
                document.getElementById("countdowntimer").textContent = timeleft;
                if (timeleft <= 0) {
                    clearInterval(interval); // how I do clearInterval
                }
            },
            5000
        );
        // Pending
        document.getElementById("nehaPending").innerHTML = "I'm working right now, I need 5 seconds";

    }

    neha();
```

Answer (score -1):

Function 'setInterval' returns a number that represents the ID value of the timer. You use this ID with the function 'clearInterval' to cancel the timer. Something like:
'var timerHandle=setInterval(alert("hello"),5000);
...
...
clearInterval(timerHandle); //cancels the timer'

More on set interval: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp